# Whats the point of publishing Gmail password lists?

Tags: email, gmail, account-security

Almost everyday some media outlet reports that a bunch of accounts have been pasted on the internet and some of them include both email-id and password. But I don't understand how this is useful. Even if you know the email-id and password you can't just login since gmail by default will prevent suspicious logins, so whats the point of making them public? Like what are hackers trying to achieve?

Comment: How about using the same password for accessing other accounts of the user? This is quite possible that a user has same passwords for many of his online accounts.

Comment: Bragging rights to say that they were successful in breaching the target systems and company.

Comment: It also gives a little more weight to dictionary attacks each time a paste of passwords is released.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm not sure lists of Gmail account details are published daily. As far as I know, Gmail has not been a major data breach (but subsets of data could of course come from other sources).

But why is the data useful? Some reasons:

- Gmail try to catch suspicious looking login attempts. I think this is mainly done by looking at the geolocation of the IP and the HTTP user agent header. But what if the attacker uses a VPN ending up in an area near where you live, and the same browser as you do? (Plus, I am not sure Gmail always blocks logins - sometimes it just notifies you of the unusual attempt but still allows it. I am not sure what policy they have.)
- Even if you can not use the passwords on Gmail, accounts might be created with the same details on other sites with less strict security. Accession those could be of value for an attacker.
- As [shroeder](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder) says in comments: "Bragging rights to say that they were successful in breaching the target systems and company." (I don't think this is the most importnat motivator, but it is one.)

The bottom line is that you should not rely on Gmails heuristics to keep your account safe. If your password is leaked, that is bad and you should change it on all places you use it.